# Problem with datepicker: Missing instance data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a dynamic HTML table created using json data. I want to create an extra column for datapicker plugin. My requirement is that when I click on a particular datapicker cell for the corresponding row, an input field should be created in that cell. When this input is clicked, the datapicker for this particular row should be invoked. I should be able to pick-up the date of my choice from the inline calender(this functionality is provided by the datapicker).In my case this date pick-up is not happening, rather this error is appearing:
Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker
[This is the jsfiddle link to the code:](https://jsfiddle.net/0akqg9b8/3/)
https://jsfiddle.net/0akqg9b8/3/

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta content="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p class="message box"></p>
    </div>
    <style>
      #myelement {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      border: 0.06em solid #999;
      border-spacing: 0.3em;
      box-shadow: 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em #999;
      background: #a1deee;
    }
    #myelement tr{
       color: blue;
    }
    #myelement td {
      width: 10%;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: 0.1em solid #000;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
    button {
      width: 10%;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: 0.1em solid #000;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
    button:hover {
      background-color: #0F5897;
      border: 1px solid #0F5897;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
 var keys;
    var myValue;
    var myVar;
    var myTableRows = [];
    var html;
    var table;
    var c;
    var myRow;
    var myCol;


json = [{
    ShipperID: 1,
    CompanyName: "Federal Package",
    Phone: "(503) 555-9931"
  },
  {
    ShipperID: 2,
    CompanyName: "United Package",
    Phone: "(503) 655-7865"
  },
  {
    ShipperID: 3,
    CompanyName: "My Package",
    Phone: "(508) 955-8997"
  }
];


getMyData();

function getMyData() {
  let myData = json[0];
  let myTablehead = [];
  myTablehead.push(myData);
  html = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    myTableRows.push(json[i])
  }
  myTablehead.forEach(function(val) {
    keys = Object.keys(val);
    //html table starts here
    html += "<table class='myTable' id=\"myelement\">"
    html += "<tr>";
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      html += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
    });
    html += "";
    html += "</tr>";
  });
  myTableRows.forEach(function(val) {
    mykeys = Object.keys(val);
    //Set up the html row
    html += "<tbody id=\"myRows\">"
    html += "<tr class=\"thisRow\">"
    for (var mykeys in val) {
      myValue = val[mykeys];
      html += "<td class='normalBtn'>"
      html += myValue;
      html += "</td>";
    }

    html += "<td class=\"dateBtn\">"
    html += "Enter Date:";
    html += "<input type = \"text\" class='datepicker-1'>"
    html += "</td>";

    html += "</tr>";
  });

  html += "</tbody>"
  html += "</table>";
  document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].innerHTML += html;
}

$(".dateBtn").on('click','input',function(){
    $("input").remove('.datepicker-1');
})

$.fn.timeline = function() {
  return this.click(function(){
    var myinput = "<input type = \"text\" class='datepicker-1' val=''></input>";
     $(this).append(myinput);
     var dataInstance = $( ".datepicker-1" ).datepicker();
     $("input:text").val(function(n){
          return dataInstance;
     });
  })
}

$(".dateBtn" ).timeline();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have some browser cache/incompatibility issues. For me, there's no error, but into the field `[object Object]` will be written and when I selecting a date from the picker nothing happening... And if I click to one of the fields, all the other fields going to be missing (removed).

Comment: In my case, same error appears in all the browsers: Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge. Something strange, in case of chrome, the date is duly picked for third row datapicker only, for the top two, this particular error appears... And if I click to one of the fields, none ofl the other fields going to be missing /removed.

Comment: Ahh this error happening when I try to select a date from the picker.

Comment: golddragon007 Kindly suggest some solution to this problem...

Comment: I made a working one where you can select for every row a date with the picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some changes in the code, because there was a lot of not really needed part.

```js
var keys;
    var myValue;
    var myVar;
    var myTableRows = [];
    var c;
    var myRow;
    var myCol;


json = [{
    ShipperID: 1,
    CompanyName: "Federal Package",
    Phone: "(503) 555-9931"
  },
  {
    ShipperID: 2,
    CompanyName: "United Package",
    Phone: "(503) 655-7865"
  },
  {
    ShipperID: 3,
    CompanyName: "My Package",
    Phone: "(508) 955-8997"
  }
];


getMyData();

function generateDateInput() {
  let input = $('<input>').attr({'type': 'text', 'class': 'datepicker-1'});
  input.datepicker();
  input.on('focus', function() {
    // The datepopup activates by the focus, not by the click.
    // So let's remove every input which is not in focus.
    $('.myTable input:not(:focus())').remove();
  }).on('click', function(event) {
    // This needed to stop bubbling effect down to the tr.
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  return input;
}

function getMyData() {
  let myData = json[0];
  let myTablehead = [];
  myTablehead.push(myData);
  let table = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    myTableRows.push(json[i])
  }
  myTablehead.forEach(function(val) {
    keys = Object.keys(val);
    //html table starts here
    table = $('<table>', document).attr({'class': 'myTable', 'id': 'myelement'});
    let tr = $('<tr>');
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      tr.append($("<th>").text(key));
    });
    table.append(tr);
  });
  let tbody = $('<tbody>').attr('id', 'myRows');
  myTableRows.forEach(function(val) {
    mykeys = Object.keys(val);
    //Set up the html row
    let tr = $('<tr>').attr('class', 'thisRow');
    for (var mykeys in val) {
      tr.append(
        $('<td>').attr('class', 'normalBtn').text(val[mykeys])
      );
    }
    
    tr.append(
      $('<td>').attr('class', 'dateBtn').text('Enter Date:').append(generateDateInput())
    ).on('click', function() {
      $('td:eq(3)', this).append(generateDateInput());
      // After append we set the focus to the input field from the current row. This
      // will only work in the current form until there's only one input field.
      $('input', this).focus();
    });
    
    tbody.append(tr);
  });
  table.append(tbody);
  $('#container').append(table);
}
```

```css
#myelement {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      border: 0.06em solid #999;
      border-spacing: 0.3em;
      box-shadow: 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em #999;
      background: #a1deee;
    }
    #myelement td {
      width: 10%;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: 0.1em solid #000;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
    button {
      width: 10%;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: 0.1em solid #000;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
    button:hover {
      background-color: #0F5897;
      border: 1px solid #0F5897;
    }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta content="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.min.js"></script>

    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p class="message box"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahaa ! It is elegant and smooth ! Now I'm trying to remove input element after the date vaue is picked...

Comment: ahh, so that wasn't a bug, I thought it is :D let me edit my response :D

Comment: @HDhindsa now I think I included everything which was existing previously, but the popup works.

Comment: @golddragon007I'm still not able to save my previous cell date as I move on to another cell in next row

Comment: I suppose my original construct was well placed to handle the problem in a non-complex way... Albeit with some little changes along with "event delegation". I can provide the solution if someone needs...